# JavaScript alert not working in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android

In my application I am using `WebView` and in that I am using `JavaScript alert( )` method but its not working, no pop-up appears.

in my manifest file I have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

and in activity file I have added

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/demo.html");
```

In layout xml file I have added

```
<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Any clue how to enable full `JavaScript` in `WebView`?

---

**Update**

Thanks mark
 the `alert()` method in the `html` file are working now :) .

Now there are two issues in `WebView` :
1: I am using a `<textarea>` in the html file that i am loading in `WebView` , and trying to write in Hindi language font in it, but when i try to write Hindi text it displays as symbols (  rectangle symbols like [] ) .

when i do the same in firefox browser on desktop it works fine.
any clue how to give support for multiple language in `textarea` in `WebView` ?

2: When I am clicking submit and trying to open the value of text in `alert()` method in another java script it doesn't work , does it mean even after using `WebChromeClient` 
its applicable only for current loaded html page and not `javascripts` called from that page ?

Comment: It's "JavaScript", not "Java Script", "java-script", or "Java script" (all of which appeared in your original question). I've corrected it for you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I would venture to say it should be called *Javascript*.

Comment: @KrisSelbekk: Nope. :-) "JavaScript" is a registered trademark of Oracle (gotta love mergers and acquisitions), and used (with permission) [by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript) for their implementation. In both cases, *with* the capital S. That's the only normative form of that name. The other name for the language, of course, is ECMAScript (or ES), but no one really uses it except when talking about [ES5](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/).

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Check [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=752) link , and last comment , You have to use `WebChromeClient` for your purpose.

Comment: thank you!  webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    
    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url,
      String message, JsResult result) {
     return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
    }
   });

Comment: your comment helped me.. as does the Nikhil's answer below.

Comment: Works like charm. But then.... does WebClient have any advantage over WebChromeClient.

Comment: It may be a stupid question, but anyway: why override a method to only call a super's method with the same params?

Comment: Don't forget to add `webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: @MuhammadSufiyan can u help me my JS is  not working in webview alrady tried solution but nothing works

Comment: @Erum write your question with your tried code so far.. and explain what you want to achieve and what problem you are getting in implementation ... I bet... there's lot of people here to help you out... and I will too try.. to help you out...

Comment: @MuhammadSufiyan  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41547303/js-confirm-box-in-android-webview-not-working

Answer (score 136):

As others indicated, setting the WebChromeClient is needed to get `alert()` to work. It's sufficient to just set the default WebChromeClient():

```java
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Thanks for all the comments below. Including John Smith's who indicated that you needed to enable JavaScript.

Comment: yes but most of the times you want to tweak with the events of the WebChromeClient so...

Comment: I finally managed to have it work by adding  `mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`before the line `mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());`

Comment: Don't forget to add `webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 27):

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
    }
});
```

Comment: This works great, but when I call `prompt` from javascript, instead of displaying the prompt text it says, "The page at https://... says:" totally breaking the immersion of the WebView being embedded in the app

Answer (score 6):

The following code will work:

```
private WebView mWebView;
final Activity activity = this;

// private Button b;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
        }
    });

    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/raw/NewFile1.html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try with this, it worked for me**

```
WebView wb_previewSurvey=new WebView(this); 


       wb_previewSurvey.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
            //Required functionality here
            return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to hide URL from the user, Show an AlertDialog as below.

```
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onJsAlert url: " + url + "; message: " + message);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        mContext);
                builder.setMessage(message)
                        .setNeutralButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }).show();
                result.cancel();
                return true;
            }
    }
```