# Integrate javascript in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript alert not working in Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271898/javascript-alert-not-working-in-android-webview)

I am developing an app in which i have to use java script but i am unable to get desired results . My java code is as follows:

```
 myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/neww.html");

            WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

//          myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
```

My html code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function show_alert( ){ 
            alert("I am an alert box!");
        }
        </script> 
    </head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Show alert box" />
</body>
 </html>
```

### When the app starts, this page gets displayed...:

[image: when the app loads this page is displayed]

### ...and when i click on show alert box it shows nothing and the following screen appears:

[image: and when i click on show alert box it shows nothing and the following screen appears]

Comment: And what results *are* you getting?

Comment: simchona, i have edited my question and i have mentioned that i am getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     function show_alert( )
```

here it seems extra space is given between "(" and  ")". try this

```
       function show_alert()
```

May be it will solve.

Comment: Extra whitespace in JavaScript doesn't matter, so this would make no difference.

Comment: @harrison_m but he put show_alert( ) at line 5

Comment: Mishu Cn , the space is not the issue , i have checked the space

Comment: @Aditya1510 http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=752 check this if it helps u

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your script block.  Change `show_alert(` to `show_alert()` on line 5 of your HTML page and it should function.