# Local HTML file not working properly in Android Webview

Tags: java, android

I have an HTML file with button, The button will popup an alert message when we click on to the button.

I placed the HTML file assets folder, Its correctly loading to the emulator and i can see the button but the issue i am facing is, the button click is not responsive, I cant see the popup message.

I also enabled the JavaScript but the result was negative. Then I changed the alert event to  the JavaScript code but not worked. Here I am adding my code, I appreciate if anybody can help.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(com.example.test.R.layout.activity_main);

     myWebView= (WebView) findViewById(com.example.test.R.id.webView1);
     myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myown.html"); 
}
```

The following is my HTML page code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a Look this, It might Help You

[Link1][1]


[Link2][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271898/javascript-alert-not-working-in-android-webview
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview

Comment: Take a Look this, It might Help You

[Link1][1]


[Link2][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271898/javascript-alert-not-working-in-android-webview
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `webChromeClient` and override `onJsAlert()` function for this purpose:

```
WebView wv=new WebView(this);   
wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
                //Do what you need to after alert is received
                return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit> This might not be the simplest solution, but it does offer extra functionality

When I created something similar, it worked on 4.1.2. The alert gave a nice, holo styled popup. I used an online resource, and a [webchromeclient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html) (see answer before me).

However, if you want to be sure this works, you might want to take a look at [Building Web Apps in Webview](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) page from Android Developers. It explains the [JavaScriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29). You can use that to couple javascript from your HTML page (local, or online) but have it execute native Java code instead.

EG You can use HTML like this

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me!" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello World!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

Add this class

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
Context mContext;

/** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

After that, add this code to the sample you provided.

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
```

Answer (score -1):

The below code is from my production environment and is completely working, I have stored the `html` file into my `assest` folder and then accessing it into an `Activity`.

**Code:**

```
String uri = "file:///android_asset/htmlpages/" + index + ".htm";
WebView wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_Glossary);
wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wb.loadUrl(uri);
```