# How to call javascript method from android

Tags: javascript, android, css, webview

Hi In my android phonegap app i need to call the javascript method from android code (DroidGap).I have tried the sample code.

Here is my code:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
super.loadUrl("javascript:onload()");
```

When i use super.loadUrl("javascript:alert('hai')"); i am getting this alert.But when i use the method "onload" i am getting the error.

Here is my error in logcat:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'onload' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function at null:1
```

Here is my script in index.html:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function onload()
 {
     alert("hai");
 }
 </script>
```

I dont know where i am wrong.Please guide me.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript alert not working in Android WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271898/javascript-alert-not-working-in-android-webview)

Comment: here is working example try this http://polamreddyn.blogspot.in/2013/05/php-alert-dialog-in-webview.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this one and add this line also

```
    super.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

After this line call like this [onPageFinished](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {                      
  @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  {     

       webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {alert("hai") }
      );                         
   }                
});
```

Comment: I am using Droidgap so i used super.loadUrl

Comment: I have tried your code but i cannot able to super instead i used webview.Now i didnt get any error but no use,alert is not coming.Please guide me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29603/discussion-between-nagarjunareddy-and-sudha)

Comment: here is example try this http://polamreddyn.blogspot.in/2013/05/php-alert-dialog-in-webview.html

Answer (score 0):

Android can only call the javascript method if an html page is currently loaded in webView

first call

webview.loadUrl("Your html page url");
then call

webView.loadUrl("javascript:hello()");

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle the alert function in the java file, like this :

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());    

    final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {        

        @Override       
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view,String url,        
                                 String message,JsResult result) {        

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).       
                setTitle("Alert").setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK",       
           new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {       
                    @Override      
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {       

                   }       
            }).create().show();       
           result.confirm();        
            return super.onJsConfirm(view,url,message, result);        
        }    

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I moved the target javascript function from the main page to an separate .js file. For some reason, the loadUrl() function can't find externally-loaded functions - only the ones in the main page. Once I moved the function back, it immediately started working.

Go figure.