# onkeypress event not firing in Android Webview 4.4

Tags: javascript, android, html, keyboard, android-webview

OnKeyPress is not being called in android webview... My Html code is simple

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="myFunc()"/>

function myFunc(){
alert(fired up!);
}
```

All the other keyevents i.e keyup, keydown are working.

Comment: @RemeesMSyde My code is so simple there is a textbox with attached keypress event all the other events like onkeyup/down are working but not this one

Comment: Are you sure that this "alert" is working fine?

Check this link [JavaScript alert not working in Android WebView][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271898/javascript-alert-not-working-in-android-webview

Comment: Yes alerts are working fine its just the keypress event that's not working

Answer (score 0):

- Try to use WebChromeClient for loading it.
- Try to build with lower version. Because in latest version API 17 and above they added **JavascriptInterface**. You need to include this as a seperate class that extends JavascriptInterface.

   To reduce application compatibility try to build with **16** or below.

Answer (score 0):

Android Webview really doesn't fire `onkeypress` event (even on newer versions of Android).

One posible solution is to replace it with `onkeyup` or `onkeydown`, like this:

```
<input type="number" onkeyup="myFunc()"/>

function myFunc(){
   alert(fired up!);
}
```