# java - How to sign in from my app to a website then open a new activity with a webview signed in

Tags: java, android, webview

i know it is pretty confused and hard, but let's give it a try. I tried everything, made researches, and still don't know how to do it. I have a webview in activity(WebView.class), and i have sign in activity (login.class) 2 edit text in login , and i connect them with the php database (the same db to the website),
so i want when i login , put some ExtraStrings `intent.putExtra("edt.getText().to.String()` etc.. to the another activty and type them in the register page of the website and sign in, is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can run javascript on that page which takes value from intent's extra and add them in your input fields and submit the form.

The following link will help you how to run javascript from android
[Run javascript code in Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163517/run-javascript-code-in-webview)