# Webview cannot load javascript at onPageFinished

Tags: javascript, java, android

I want my webview insert sort of javascript after a page has been loaded. However, the javascript I added has never been executed:( what can I do on this?

```
mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            Log.d("WebClient", "onPageFinished");
            view.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){"+
                    "aTagElements=document.getElementsByTagName('a');" +
                    "randromElement=aTagElements[Math.floor(Math.random() * aTagElements.length)];"+
                    "clickEvent=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');"+
                    "clickEvent.initEvent('click',true,true);"+
                    "randromElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);" +
                    "alert('event dispatched.');"+ //<---not called
                    "})()");
        }
});
```

Even if I comment out all the scripts except the `alert` line, still nothing happens.

Comment: Where is the url of the webpage you want to load

Comment: @ManojPerumarath whatever url, my code does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `evaluvateJavascript`, `loadUrl` will work only in old version.

```
webview.evaluateJavascript("(function() { "javascript:(function(){"+
                "aTagElements=document.getElementsByTagName('a');" +
                "randromElement=aTagElements[Math.floor(Math.random() * aTagElements.length)];"+
                "clickEvent=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');"+
                "clickEvent.initEvent('click',true,true);"+
                "randromElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);" +
                "alert('event dispatched.');";
```

[EvaluvateJavascript](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#evaluateJavascript%28java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29)

Comment: it takes 2 parameters and the 2nd one is a value callback. I put a logging in the callback and it shows the log but the javascript (even the alert one) is not executed.

Comment: did you try it only using alert?

Comment: I tried on a simple html made by myself and it works now! I grab up 2 things that mislead me. 1) users cannot see the generated click events occurred 2) alert function works in my simple html, perhaps the alert was blocked by other websites that I thought the script does not work.

Answer (score 2):

**You will have to use like this on application side**

```
mWebView .addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

**and will have to implement method on php side where actually this method will be trigger**

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**on PHP Side implement like this**

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

For a complete reference, you can go through on [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#java)

Whenever you will click the button on `webView` then you will get a message

Comment: My code is to create a 'click' behavior in the loaded HTML, this example may not fit me. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @SimonLeung, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163517/run-javascript-code-in-webview?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @Simon Leung, What is the issue now you are getting?

Comment: Inserting javascript after the page is loaded. evaluateJavascript gives me the callback but the javascript does not run.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing views. So change

`super.onPageFinished(view, url);`

To

`super.onPageFinished(mWebView, url);`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below solution may it works for you.

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```