# How to postMessage to a webview inside a native android app?

Tags: android, html

*I want to open a web view **inside an android app** and post a message to that window like we do `window.postMessage` in the browser.*

How can we do that with web *views inside an Android app*?

Comment: look into this post [run-javascript-code-in-webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163517/run-javascript-code-in-webview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call

```
WebView.loadUrl("Javascript:window.postMessage")
```

if i'm not mistaken.