# How to call a Kotlin function from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, kotlin, android-webview

I am trying to fill a `TextView` located inside `WebView` (in Android) with random email generated by `Kotlin` `function` using JavaScript but not found any solution.

My `Kotlin` `function` for generating random email address

```
fun getSaltString(): String? {
    val SALTCHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
    val salt = StringBuilder()
    val rnd = Random()
    while (salt.length < 7) { // length of the random string.
        val index = (rnd.nextFloat() * SALTCHARS.length) as Int
        salt.append(SALTCHARS[index])
    }
    return salt.toString()
}
```

And here is the call to the above function using Kotlin `getSaltString()+"@gmail.com"` but what I don't know how to call it from `JavaScript`?

My `JavaScript` call so far

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById(\"user_email_login\").value = \"I don't know how to call @gmail.com\";\n})()");
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder WebView in android. I just want to automate form filling by doing this.

Comment: *(How did I miss the first sentence?! Sorry.)*

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163517/run-javascript-code-in-webview?

Comment: @Berto99 I think my question is not matching with the above-suggested answer.

Comment: Yes, that question is the reverse. @ElizabethHarper the official documentation on how to do this is here: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have time to test this, but hopefully it's right. You need a class that contains your function(s) that you want to be able to call from JS. An instance of this class will be bound to your WebView. Each function in the class needs the annotation `@JavascriptInterface` before it.

I made the content of your function more concise, just as a tip.

```
class WebAppInterface {

    @JavascriptInterface
    fun getSaltString(): String = buildString {
        val saltChars = ('A'..'Z').toList() + ('0'..'9').toList()
        repeat(7) {
            append(saltChars.random())
        }
    }

}
```

Then you register an instance of this class with the webview. Whatever String name you pass here will be what you prepend calls with in your JS:

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(), "Android")
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById(\"user_email_login\").value = Android.getSaltString() + \"@gmail.com\";\n})()");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it was very simple at least in my case.

What I need to fill my Email `TextBox` In (Android WebView) randomly generated by the `Kotlin Function`.

**My Function For Generating Random Text**

```
fun getSaltString(): String? {
    val SALTCHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
    val salt = StringBuilder()
    val rnd = Random()
    while (salt.length < 7) { // length of the random string.
        val index = (rnd.nextFloat() * SALTCHARS.length).toInt()
        salt.append(SALTCHARS[index])
    }
    return salt.toString()
}
```

Now I declared **two** `variables` to hold the value of my random email.

```
 val temporaryEmailaddress: String? = getSaltString()
 val EmailAddressFinal: String? = "$temporaryEmailaddress@gmail.com"
```

And finally, a simple call to the `EmailAddressFinal` variable is done the trick. :)

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById(\"user_email_login\").value = \"$EmailAddressFinal\";\n})()");
```