# How to show a Javascript permission popup in an Android WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview, getusermedia

I am building an Android app with a `WebView` that shows a website. On 1 page on this website, it asks the user to allow camera permission (using `getUserMedia()` in Javascript). When I visit this page in a normal browser (pc or mobile), it correctly shows the popup where the user can allow or deny access. However, when visiting this page through the `WebView` in my app, this popup is not shown at all.

For the `WebViewClient`, I'm using this code:

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl("https://example.com/");

WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled (true);
```

I've also tried using the `WebChromeClient`, and the popup is shown there. However the problem with that is that it opens a whole new app (the Chrome browser) and I don't think there's a way to go back to my app programatically.

I have a few solutions in mind but I don't know which one works or is possible at all:

1. Only use `WebViewClient` and make it show JS popups. Is this possible?
2. Use `WebChromeClient` for the page that needs camera permission, and use `WebViewClient` for all other pages. Problem: How do I temporarily open the camera page and go back to the app when the user clicks allow/deny?

Any advice on this? Crazy workarounds are also very much welcome.

Comment: Based on permission inherit from chromeClient https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271898/javascript-alert-not-working-in-android-webview.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329662/android-webview-geolocation